# Как добавить еще 1 спрайт в спрайтшит?

Tags: unity3d

Есть набор спрайтов в 1 файле(спрайтшит/коллекция), как добавить в этот же файл еще 1 спрайт?

Если менять файл, загружать по новой — приходится заново его разрезать на части, настраивать pivot (а его часто нельзя на глаз установить в тоже место где он был), из-за этого немного ломается анимация и т.д., давать каждому элементу имя, а затем раскидывать их по всем объектам.

Есть ли какой-то способ просто дополнить/заменить спрайт в существующем файле в ассетах?

Comment: Ох сомнительно. Возможно что-то можно сделать используя SpriteEditor и атласы.....но это не точно..... Попробуй задать тот же вопрос на http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  ......

Comment: Тоже сомневаюсь, что это возможно. Скорее всего придётся делать новый спрайт и заново настраивать всё.

Answer (score 0):

Ну а программно кто мешает? Извлекаете спрайты, сохраняете их позиции пивот размеры, добавляете новый и пакуете снова в файл. Примеры можно посмотреть в asset store, какой-нибудь texture packer, или бесплатный simple sprite packer